# Monitor Solr using prometheus and Grafana

Tags: solr, prometheus, grafana

I think I am missing something here.

I installed prometheus[`2.18 Darwin`], Grafana[`7.0`]. I started solr exporter which is part of solr[`8.1`]. It started and didn't throw any error.

Then added prometheus as a data source in grafana. I added job name and solr url in scrape section.

```
scrape_configs:
# The job name is added as a label `job=<job_name>` to any timeseries   
scraped from this config.
- job_name: 'solr'

# metrics_path defaults to '/metrics'
# scheme defaults to 'http'.

static_configs:
- targets: ['localhost:9854']
```

When I see `localhost:9854/graph` it gives me the metrics. It is prometheus url. I tried to load JSON in contrib/prometheus-exporter/conf to Grafana.

It shows `cannot read property 'result' of undefined`

How do I link all these three? I followed [solr reference guide](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_3/monitoring-solr-with-prometheus-and-grafana.html) and few GitHub links. But I don't have much knowledge about prometheus and Grafana. I want to see solr metrics.

I see this in grafana log.

> `t=2020-05-21T19:16:28+0530 lvl=info msg="Request Completed" logger=context userId=1 orgId=1 uname=admin method=GET path=/api/datasources/proxy/1/api/v1/query status=502 remote_addr=[::1] time_ms=59134 size=0 referer=http://localhost:3000/datasources/edit/1/
>   t=2020-05-21T21:15:46+0530 lvl=eror msg="Data proxy error" logger=data-proxy-log userId=1 orgId=1 uname=admin path=/api/datasources/proxy/1/api/v1/query_range remote_addr=[::1] referer="http://localhost:3000/d/NuzWo3gMk/solr-dashboard?orgId=1&refresh=1m" error="http: proxy error: read tcp [::1]:62395->[::1]:9854: read: connection reset by peer"
>   t=2020-05-21T21:15:46+0530 lvl=info msg="Request Completed" logger=context userId=1 orgId=1 uname=admin method=GET path=/api/datasources/proxy/1/api/v1/query_range status=502 remote_addr=[::1] time_ms=3 size=0 referer="http://localhost:3000/d/NuzWo3gMk/solr-dashboard?orgId=1&refresh=1m"`

I started `Solr-exporter` using `./bin/solr-exporter -p 9854 -b http://localhost:8983/solr -f ./conf/solr-exporter-config.xml &`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the metrics-path as '/' in the prometheus yml config

```
 - job_name: 'Solr'
    metrics_path: '/'
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['localhost:9854']
      - labels :
          group: core
```